# Group some part of the flowable stream

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

Suppose that I have a flowable stream like below:

A B C C C D E F

I want to combine all of C into one list. Final output must be like that:

A B [C, C, C] D E F

I tried to use groupBy operator but couldn't make it happen.

Comment: Is C known or should the repeat indicate turning them into a list (i.e., if E repeated, that should also turn into list)? Note that either way, the output flow's type can only be the intersection of the item and list type, which will likely end up as `Flowable<Object>` or `Flowable<List<T>>` where A, B, D, E, F become singleton lists each.

Comment: Yes, C is known but if E repeated that should not turn into a list except F, it should depend on the object type. 

i.e, A B C C C D E E E F F 

Final output should be A B [C, C, C], D E E E [F, F]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can get somewhat complicated because you have to remember the previous items and delay their emission. Here is a transformer which should allow you to customize what is considered an item to be grouped:

```
import java.util.*;

import org.junit.Test;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.ObservableTransformer;
import io.reactivex.functions.Predicate;

public class ListGrouping {

    static class Group {
        List<String> grouped;
        String groupKey;
    }


    static boolean groupCE(String t) {
        return "C".equals(t) || "E".equals(t);
    }

    static ObservableTransformer<String, Object> group(
            Predicate<? super String> groupCheck) {
        return strings -> 
        Observable.defer(() -> {
            Group gr = new Group();
            return strings
                    .flatMap(t -> {
                        if (gr.grouped != null) {
                            if (!t.equals(gr.groupKey)) {
                                List<String> g = gr.grouped;
                                if (groupCheck.test(t)) {
                                    gr.groupKey = t;
                                    gr.grouped = new ArrayList<>();
                                    gr.grouped.add(t);
                                    if (g.size() == 1) {
                                        return Observable.just(g.get(0));
                                    }
                                    return Observable.just(g);
                                }
                                gr.groupKey = null;
                                gr.grouped = null;
                                if (g.size() == 1) {
                                    return Observable.just(g.get(0), t);
                                }
                                return Observable.just(g, t);
                            }
                            gr.grouped.add(t);
                            return Observable.empty();
                        }
                        if (groupCheck.test(t)) {
                            gr.grouped = new ArrayList<>();
                            gr.groupKey = t;
                            gr.grouped.add(t);
                            return Observable.empty();
                        }
                        return Observable.just(t);
                    })
                    .concatWith(Observable.defer(() -> {
                        if (gr.grouped != null) {
                            if (gr.grouped.size() == 1) {
                                return Observable.just(gr.grouped.get(0));
                            }
                            return Observable.just(gr.grouped);
                        }
                        return Observable.empty();
                    }));
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Observable.fromArray("ABCCCDEF".split(""))
        .compose(group(ListGrouping::groupCE))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
        ;

        System.out.println("----");

        Observable.fromArray("ABCEFEECCC".split(""))
        .compose(group(ListGrouping::groupCE))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
        ;
    }
}
```